# Level of maths of engineers in the Industrial Revolution

Tags: mathematics, calculus, engineering

Did engineers like I.K. Brunel and his contemporaries employ calculus in their constructions? Or did they work just with 'rules of the thumb' and useful 'laws' like the square-cube...? What was the level of maths (beyond simple algebra and trigonometry) used by engineers in those times?

Answer (score 2):

[Brunel (1806-1859)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isambard_Kingdom_Brunel) in 1822 was a candidate to the [École Polytechnique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89cole_Polytechnique).

[Augustin-Louis Cauchy (1789-1857)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augustin-Louis_Cauchy) graduated in civil engineering and in 1816 was appointed professor at École Polytechnique.

The seminal [Cours d'Analyse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cours_d%27Analyse) was published by Cauchy in 1821 as *Cours d'Analyse de l’École Royale Polytechnique*.

On this ground, we have to presume that the calculus was part of Brunel's professional knowledge.

Comment: It would be interesting if the curriculum for engineers at École Polytechnique in 1822 could be found.

Comment: I don't doubt the mathematical prowess of Brunel, to say nothing of Cauchy. What I'm asking is about the maths that 19th century engineers used in practice...

Comment: He was not accepted to Ecole polytechnique. So its curriculum is irrelevant when we are talking about Brunel. He previously studied in a prestigious Lycee Henri IV, but it is not clear whether he was taught calculus. It is more likely that he was self-educated in higher mathematics.